# wordpress, how remove the padlock in my site (due to 1 image)

Tags: wordpress, https

i have a website (done with wordpress) and the problem is:
When i use chrome or chromium, my https is okay, but when i try it with mozilla, i have  a padlock, there is the message in my console.

```
Chargement du contenu mixte d’affichage « http:/montagne.jpg » (non sécurisé) sur une page sécurisée

Chargement du contenu mixte d’affichage « https:/montagne.jpg » (non sécurisé) sur une page sécurisée

"english traduction":
Loading mixed display content "http: /montagne.jpg" (not secure) on a secure page
```

When i look my image montagne.jpg in my wordpress the url is  https:/montagne.jpg

How is it possible? and How can i change that?

Thanks for yours answers.